# Latex Tikz 3D plot magnetic field lines through current loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw something like this in latex tikz? I'm familiar with tikz in 2D space but I never came across drawing something in 3D.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: How would you draw it as an artist? Translate that intoTikz.